# Same library with distinct version

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I am developing a Azure Web Site with asp.net core, but I have a problem with dll version.

I am using some compoment developing internally, but two use other compoment with distinct version. I know that `GAC`, `<probing>` can solve the problem but the enviroment is Azure.

With asp.net core can reference distint library by .net framework

[image]

Can I reference by framework two dll with distinct version ?

**Expanded the question**

I have two third-party libraries, don't have the code. One library use Newtonsoft.Json with version 8.x and the other library uses 7.x

When the asp.net mvc application is builded there is conflict with the Newtonsoft.Json version copied to bin folder

Comment: Do you mean if you can load an assembly with different versions into one App? No. They need to have at least different versions. One of the reasons why Entity Framework Core assembly was renamed, in order to allow loading of EF Core 1.0 and EF6 in the same Application

Comment: thanks for your answer. I extend the question with compilation problem when the web application is builded